# Set Read and Publish Facebook Permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-permissions

I have a problem with the facebook permission. I need the email and credentials of the user. So I used:

```
this.buttonLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
```

Then I need to publish a post using Open Graph Stories, so I call this method:

```
this.buttonLoginFacebook.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");
```

But these method can't be used togheder. 
How can I do? Is necessary to use publish_actions permission to post using OpenGrapStories? Because without work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation

> **The LoginButton can only be associated with either read permissions or
>   publish permissions, but not both**. Calling both setReadPermissions and
>   setPublishPermissions on the same instance of LoginButton will result
>   in an exception being thrown unless clearPermissions is called in
>   between.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/

Comment: How can I set Read and Publish permission?